# How to change the timeout only for some specific XML-RPC calls

Tags: c++, curl, xml-rpc, long-polling

I'm using the XML-RPC for C/C++ (over CURL) client library in version 1.25.23 to:

- *send data to* ...

and

- *receive (poll) events from* ...

...XML-RPC application server.

To reduce the data traffic (while polling the events) i'm trying  to implement the "long polling" mechanism for some (!) specific methods. To do so i need to change the "Global Request Timeout" value only for those calls to "no timeout", wich is different from the global timeout value (e.g. 3 sec.). Unfortunately i  don't see the possibility to do so, without to destroy and recreate the global client instance (xmlrpc_client_cleanup / xmlrpc_client_init2) for every single request!!!! i dont think it would be a good solution.

Has anybody experience in implementation of "long polling" with XML-RPC over CURL?

Thank You in advance!
Max

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bryan Henderson!!

> I can think of two things.
>
> First, you don't have to use the global XML-RPC client.  You could
>   have two private clients - use one for regular XML-RPC RPCs and the
>   other one for RPCs that take a long time.
>
> http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/doc/libxmlrpc_client.html#privateclient
>
> The other thing you can do is not use the Curl transport timeout and
>   instead use an alarm signal (SIGALRM) to interrupt RPCs that are
>   taking too long.
>
> http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/doc/libxmlrpc_client.html#interrupting

The idea of "private client" did it for me!!!